# SQL Exception being thrown from view about model attribute not being currently accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting the following exception in my view, stories/_form.slim.  The exception seems strange because it's complaining about an attribute I'm not trying to access:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: constraints.sentence_id: SELECT  "constraints".* FROM "constraints"  WHERE "constraints"."sentence_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

The offending line is the 2nd line in stories/_form.slim:

```
...

= form_tag("/stories/#{@story.id}", :method => "put") do
  = label_tag "Type the next line in the story. You must use the word '#{@story.curr_sentence.constraint.phrase}'."

...
```

models/story.rb:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sentences, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sentences, :allow_destroy => true

  def curr_sentence
    self.sentences.find_by_turn(self.turn)
  end

  ...
end
```

models/sentence.rb:

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
  has_one :constraint
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :constraint
end
```

models/constraint.rb:

```
class Constraint < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sentences
end
```

db/schema.rb:

```
  create_table "stories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "turn",       :default => 1
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end

  create_table "sentences", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "constraint_id"
    t.integer  "story_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

  create_table "constraints", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "phrase"
    t.integer  "constraint_category_id", :limit => 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            :null => false
  end
```

Any ideas?  Been tearing my hear out trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association between sentence and constraint is wrong. You should only use [`has_one`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association) in a 1:1 relationship. This is a one-to-many relationship, so you should use `belongs_to`:

```
class Sentence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :story
  belongs_to :constraint
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :constraint
end
```